# How to create a completely autonomous Python environment?

Tags: python, usb-drive

I want to create a completely autonomous Python environment on an USB pen drive that can run both on Windows and GNU/Linux....

How can I do that ?

I've tried to build Python with `./' as prefix, but it doesn't works... anyone has another idea ?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: For Windows, try http://www.portablepython.com/. I don't know of anything equivalent for Linux, but Linux systems usually have Python on already.

Comment: Running both on Windows and Linux is pretty much impossible, unless if you make two builds (of if you use WINE, perhaps).

Comment: PortablePython looks like a distribution of the official CPython for windows, but it seems not dependent of any absolute directory... I'll see the source code...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, i've looked at http://svn.python.org/projects/python/branches/release31-maint/ and i found an interesting «[readme](//svn.python.org/projects/python/branches/release31-maint/PC/readme.txt)» talking about a «[pyconfig.h](//svn.python.org/projects/python/branches/release31-maint/PC/pyconfig.h)» file.

In http://svn.python.org/projects/python/branches/release31-maint/PC/pyconfig.h at line 82-83, there is the solution of my problem:

```
#ifndef PYTHONPATH
#   define PYTHONPATH L".\\DLLs;.\\lib;.\\lib\\plat-win"
```

I think if i change the value of the «PYTHONPATH» define, i'll get a python interpreter seeking his files in a relative directory, so I'll just have to build it both for GNU/Linux and Window, and to put the both executables on a pen-drive, then i'll get a portable Python environment !

I'm trying this, and I'll keep you posted ...

---

EDIT: Finally, it works !
I've built Python like this:

```
make PYTHONPATH=../lib:../Lib:./lib:./Lib
```

... and now Python seeks the modules in `../lib' !

I will build it both for GNU/Linux and Windows, and i'll put it on an USB pen-drive, like this:

```
/mnt/key/
├── AUTORUN.INF 
├── Lib
│   ├── os.py
│   ├── sys.py
│   ├── ...
│   └── (Here i'll put the Python Standard Library)
├── Linux
│   └── python
└── Windows
    ├── python.exe
    └── pythonw.exe
```

Thanks all